# ClassNotFoundException Android Studio debugging

Tags: debugging, emulation, classnotfoundexception, android-studio

I installed Android Studio, imported a project and started debugging. All was ok until suddenly I started the debugger and got ClassNotFoundException for the launch of the main Activity. The strange thing is that if I run the project or I debug it with a virtual device all is fine. Only the device give this problem. 
Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: My suggestion is: It's a PREVIEW version full of bugs. Stay calm and wait untill beta release.

Comment: I see, it cannot find the R.MyClass too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this. My app had been running fine and one day it just started running into these ClassNotFoundExceptions. My code hadn't changed at all.

As far as I can tell, it ended up being a bug in the build of Android Studio. I had recently updated to the latest release on the canary channel.

Switching back to an older release on the dev channel got things working again:

1. Go into Settings / IDE Settings / Update
2. Change to Dev Channel and Check Now.